# Incidence rate difference from random effects glmer in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am trying to estimate incidence rate differences from a glmer model using poisson. I can obtained the incidence rate ratio, but when I try to use identity link I get an error:

`glmIRD<-glmer(event~treat+x1+x2+x3+(1|x4)+offset(logtime),control = glmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead"), data=Data,  family=poisson(link = "identity"))`

Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  :
PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value

I have found a way to manipulate the coefficients from the IRR model with the log link to obtain an estimate of the IRD but I am unsure how accurate this is:

`glmIRR<-glmer(event~treat+x1+x2+x3+(1|x4)+offset(logtime),control = glmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead"), data=Data,  family=poisson(link = "log"))`

`IRD <-  exp(fixef(glmIRR)["(Intercept)"])*(exp(fixef(glmIRR)["TxNumeric"])-1)`

However, I have also run a model with gaussian family, and identity link, with an offset for person time, but I am not sure this is a valid method of obtaining the IRD:

`glmIRD<- glmer(event~treat+x1+x2+x3+(1|x4)+offset(logtime), data=Data1,  family=gaussian(link = "identity"))`

Is the gaussian family with an offset for person time an appropriate method to obtain the IRD, or is there a way to get the IRD from a glmer that I am missing?